# Trying to Disable Command Bar Controls on Worksheet Open VBA

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I am trying to disable a bunch of controls when the sheet opens (and then re-enable them when the sheet closes), but when opening the sheet (when the code runs), I get the error "Object variable or With block variable not set.  Here is my code:

Option Explicit

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

OptionsDisable

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Close()

OptionsEnable

End Sub

Sub OptionsDisable()

Dim myControls As CommandBarControls
Dim ctl As CommandBarControl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=21)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3181)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=292)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3125)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=855)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=1576)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=293)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=541)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3183)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=294)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=542)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=886)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=887)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=883)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=884)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = False
    Next ctl

End Sub

Sub OptionsEnable()

Dim myControls As CommandBarControls
Dim ctl As CommandBarControl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=21)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3181)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=292)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3125)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=855)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=1576)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=293)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=541)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3183)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=294)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=542)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=886)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=887)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=883)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl
    Set myControls = CommandBars.FindControls _
        (Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=884)
    For Each ctl In myControls
        ctl.Enabled = True
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, at workbook open the commandbars are not populated. stick your code in a macro and run it after everything is populated. second, there is no control with id 3181 (just fyi) I looped through all of the id's and there is no 3181, this is the second one in the list. so, you'll need to add some error handling in there. like this

```
If Not myControle Is Nothing Then

'do the loop code

End If
```

because when a specific control is not found then `myControl` gets set to `Nothing`

### edit

because the command bars are not populated on workbook open, put the code in the "SheetActivate" method of the workbook, then in the workbook open put

```
Sheets(2).Activate
Sheets(1).Activate
```

this will force the sheetactivate event to fire. its there twice because if the workbook opens on the sheet that you put first, (in my example, sheet2) then the activate does not fire. so hense, activate sheet 2, then sheet 1 (incase sheet2 was already open when the workbook opened)

Comment: Maybe you have a different version of excel, but in 2010 it is "Insert..." on the Cell commandbar:  [link](http://i.imgur.com/YggbOsj.png).

As for the other issue, I need this code to run automatically when the worksheet opens and closes, so the user cannot interfere with certain things.  A user-run macro is not going to work for my case.

Comment: maybe the insert bar isnt there in mine. in any case, error checking is a good thing. I edited my answer so that the code will fire and work

Comment: Okay, that works to disable my options when I open the sheet, but it's not working for re-enabling them when I close it. Is "Workbook_Close()" not something that exists?

Comment: Nevermind, you have to use this as your sub:  Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Comment: oh ya, i totally forgot about reenabling after. ya, it is. so in the workbook close just call the enable sub

Comment: ah yeh, not close but before close. ugh, excel and its odd names

Comment: Yeah, it's not that intuitive.

Comment: @user1759942: It is not working... it says "Time execution error 424" Object is obligatory" and points to the line --> For Each ctl In myControls. I have two sheets full of numbers and I have run the code from a macro. What is wrong?

Comment: It's very hard to know exactly why you're getting that error without seeing your code. having said that, the most likely problem is that `myControls` is not getting set properly. Where do you have this code? as stated in my answer, it will not work in a workbook open even as the commandbars are not populated when the workbook_open event happens